# Sort lookup column to show Active = Yes category on top in on edit form

Tags: lookup-column, sorting

We are on SharePoint 2016 on premise. We have one document library in which we have added look up column (Category) of existing list(Allow multiple selection). We We want to sort by Active column (yes/no). Display Categories which are Active on top.

Please suggest how can we achieve this?

Regards,

Amit Chhatbar

Comment: Hi Amit - did this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

In your question it is not clear if you are using 'Allow Multiples Selection' in a choice field - if you are, choice fields will not sort in a nice way.

i.e. `Value A` will show at the top of your sorted results; Values `A and B` will show next; then `Values A and C` next, then `A,B and D`, then `A, C and D`, then `Value B`, then `Value B and C` and so on.

However, if your values are simply 'Yes' or 'No' you should modify the view in Library settings - go to the 'Sort By' settings and choose to Sort By the **Active** field.  Show items in descending order to show the Yes values before the No.

n.b. the screenshot shows a field called ID, but you need to select your **Active** field here instead.

[image: Sort By screenshot]

You can also add a secondary Sort By, just choose another field.